# how to resolve function call in method overloading?

Tags: c++

```
void add(int,int);
void add(int ,float);
void add(float,int);

unsigned int i = 10;
unsigned float j = 1.0;
add(i,f); // ambiguios call error
```

if i remove unsigned from program then it is working fine.

```
int i = 10;
float j = 1.0;
add(i,f); // working
```

Why using unsigned variable in overloading function causes ambiguios call

Comment: `unsigned float`?  I would have understood any confusion if they were both unsigned integers, but `unsigned float` isn't a real data type last time I checked.

Comment: It's not a ℝeal data type, last time you checked?

Comment: @Dietrich: That was my subtle way of saying there is no such type thank you very much.  :P

Comment: @Jeff: I was tℝying to be funny ;-)

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing called as `unsigned float` in C++. `float` is always `signed`

As per, C++ Standard table 7 in §7.1.5.2, *"signed" by itself is a synonym for "int".*
So the compiler should give you a error, that `signed` or `unsigned` is not applicable for `float`.

Check [here](http://ideone.com/b6YXd), even Ideone reports an error.

```
error: ‘signed’ or ‘unsigned’ invalid for ‘j’
```

Are you by any chance misinterpreting this error as `ambiguos` function call error?

If you drop the `unsigned float`, the compiler cannot see any matching function call which has arguments `unsigned int` & `float`, So it promotes `unsigned int` to `int` and resolves the call to the function with arguments `int` & `float`, there is no ambiguity.

[Here](http://ideone.com/fysog) is the code sample on Ideone.

Comment: `unsigned int` -> `int` is not an integral promotion:  the two types have the same rank.  It is therefore an integral conversion, which has the same rank in overload resolution as the `float` -> `int` conversion.  Does that not make the call ambiguous because neither `void add(int, float)` nor `void add(float, int)` is unambiguously better?

Comment: @James: `void add(float, int)` requires two conversions while `void add(int,float)` only requires one.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: That is a very good reasoning for compiler to give preference to the latter verison.

Comment: it is, but I never quite grokked the algorithm for overload selection so it might not be the one used :p

Comment: @Matthieu:  Oh; duh!  Of course!  Well, now I feel dumb. :-)  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The call is ambiguous because none of your function signatures match (due to looking for signed values) and if it starts casting then it could match more than one signature, so it doesn't know which you want. Add overloads for unsigned values to avoid confusion. (Not so sure about unsigned float!)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, int means it is signed. So, when you call with an unsigned int, it sees that there is no matching function call, and it tries to type promote unsigned int to something for which a match may occur, but here, it is unable to decide to which data type it must promote itself since unsigned int can be promoted to both int and float. (I'm not sure about that "Unsigned float")

Answer (score 0):

In C++ unsigned float is treated as unsigned int and the fraction part is truncated. Hence, when you call add (i, f) it has no function to match.